# Where should we set centerOffset of MKAnnotationView?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

Should we do so in `- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation{`

Is there some sample code on proper use of

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation{
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it in *viewForAnnotation*:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{        
    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKAnnotationView *) [_mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"myIdentifier"];
    if (annotationView == nil) 
    {
        annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    } 
    else 
    {
        annotationView.annotation = annotation;
    }
    annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myPinImage.png"];
    // set your offset here
    annotationView.centerOffset = CGPointMake(offsetX, offsetY);
    return annotationView;
}
```

Comment: I think you should do annotationView.annotation=annotation too even if annotationView return nil and you recreate them. Or am i correct here?

Comment: Actually I was wrong. You already use initWithAnnotation. So the annotationView already know where the stuff are.

Comment: oh I misread your previous comment. Yea you don't have to set the annotation property again. Anyway I moved the setting of the image out of the "if" body. That was my earlier mistake that I thought you were pointing out in your previous comment.